# Template error in django for openshift

Tags: python, django

[image]

I am trying to set up a Django 1.7 project to push to openshift. I'm following https://github.com/jfmatth/openshift-django17. I've sucessfully got the initial project going on openshift, now I'm trying to move a local project into this file structure so I can deploy it.

When I run the project I get:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /index/
```

The templates are all in the static/templates folder (in the screenshot). My settings url contains:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))    

......    

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'wsgi','static')
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',    

)    

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
```

How can I get help django find the templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move out your templates from `/static/` in the parent directory, you don't want them moved to `wsgi/static` when doing `collectstatic`, then add this setting:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
)
```

Comment: Thank you, I've followed your directions. It looks like everything deployed correctly when I git pushed to openshift. However my site shows: Not Found . The requested URL / was not found on this server. Any idea what to do from here?

Comment: @user61629 you should post another question with more info for that.